# How to successfully do delete/remove operation in ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: jpa

I'm using ManyToMany with JPA annotation, I need your valuable suggestions. 
(Assume Person and Address. Same Address is referred to more person (living at same address)). I have to delete a person from that address.

```
Person p1 = new Person();
  Person p2 = new Person();
    Address add1 = new Address();

p1.add(add1);
  p2.add(add1);
```

As well doing

```
add1.add(p1)  ;
  add1.add(p2)  ;
```

THen on merge or persist iit mapped appropriately.

```
p1 - add1
   p2 - add1
```

I have to delete p2 alone , when i did

```
p2.removeAddress(add1)
 removeAddress(add1) { 
        addColelction.remove(add1) }
```

What happens is it deleted the entry for address and again by Hibernate jpa provider again tries to persist at Address entity and says "deleted entity passed to persist " and henc transaction roll back happens. 
   My correction on the question.                                                            The mapping exist as 
In Script side :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "XXXX", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "X1_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "X1_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Collection<Parser> parsers;
```

In Parser side

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parsers")
    private Collection<Script> scripts;
```

The data saved as

```
Script1 - Parser1
  Script2 - Parser1
```

Our data model is Object A has oneTomany to B , B has oneTomany to Script objects.
   Say collection of A has (B1,B2,.....)
                             B1 has (Script1)
                             B2 has (Script2)

When we want to delete that B2 object (we do just EM.merge(A)), we want the particular B2 from the collection has to be deleted and the related the Script2 has to be deleted. Script2 delete should remove the intermediate entry alone but should not delete the Parser.
      But Parser1 gets deleted and Transaction gets rolled back saying ''deleted entity passed to persist
        Please share your ideas.

Comment: could you please fix the formatting?

Comment: Can you also show how you are deleting the p2?  From the mapping, it shouldn't delete the address, so something else is happening, but note you have shown a mapping for a collection 'parsers' of Parser entities.  Is the mapping to Address different?    Note you must remove both references in a bidirectional relationship.  You call p2.removeAddress(add1), but probably should be calling add1.removePerson(p2) somehow as well or the add1 will remain referencing the p2 and you will either get a constraint error or the object model will be out of sync with the database, causing issues such as this.

Comment: I understand now.  The error isn't because address was somehow deleted, it was because you are calling persist on the address.  You have not cleaned up the address' reference to the deleted p2, so it is still there, and you likely have cascade all set.  This causes the persist operation to cascade to the deleted p2, resulting in the error.  You must maintain both sides of bidirectional relationships to prevent this problem.  Remove the p2 from address' person collection.

Comment: My correction on the question adding to it

Answer (score 0):

You mention you only want the join table cleared up, but you have both DELETE_ORPHAN and cascade all set on the Script->Parser mapping.  The first setting seems to be a hibernate option equivalent to JPA's orphan removal, which will cause any entities de-referenced from the collection to be deleted in the database.  This will cause Address1 in the example to be deleted.

The cascade all option will force the remove operation to be cascaded to any entities still referenced by Person/Script when remove is called on Person/Script.  In the first example this will cause Address2 to be removed/deleted from the database.

If you want address 1 or address2 to survive, then remove the appropriate setting.  As mentioned in comments, you will also want to clean up your references, as the survivors will be left referencing a deleted Person/Script entity which may cause problems in your application.

Comment: Chris, here both script or Person has same referenced Address object. But you have mentioned 'addess 1 or address 2', do you say two different address objects ??

Comment: I don't know, as your switch between Person-address to parser/scripts confused me.  The problem as I mentioned remains - you have cascade remove set on the relationship you showed between Script->Parser.  This means if you delete a script, it will cause all Parsers it references to be removed as well.  You also set orphan removal, which means if you de-reference a parser from this relationship, that parser will be deleted from the database.  I don't think either are what you want.